# How to redesign our network?

Tags: networking, vpn, dmz, network-topology

We currently have three networks, X.X.163.1, X.X.93.1 and 192.168.1.1. 
Today's setup is like this:

[image]

We now have PPT VPN from internet to the X.X.163.1-network, but really need to access the files from the File Server through VPN. I am also aware that this setup is not optimal. So please, any advices on how to redesign our network?

Rack servers are mostly web and db servers, with only public IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to redesign the network, a static route on the Fortigate to your internal network (with appropriate firewall rules on the Fortigate and Sonicwall box) should allow your VPN users to access the file server.

I'm making some guesses about the capabilities of your Fortigate box here, but if you want to redesign the network however you could probably lose the SonicWall box entirely and connect the 192.168.1.0 network directly into the Fortigate.  You would need to setup a new interface on the Fortigate but it might simplify getting some routing between the networks.

Answer (score 0):

From the diagram it looks like you have everything in one building - but then you talk about a vpn. Where is the vpn?

If the link from the sonicwall to to the 163 network is supposed to represent a vpn link then the link is between the two firewalls and communication between the three subnets is simply a question of modifying the rules.

If not, I'm not sure what you are doing.

If everything is in the same building, why do you have the sonicwall? The fortinets usually have a selection of ports available.

Ian

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Everything is in the same building, I need VPN from the internet and into our net. The sonicwall is attached because we did not have knowledge in setting up a different network on the fortigate; the most safe way then was to connect a router. 

You are saying I should look more into attaching our local network to a separate port on the Fortigate?